# UIWebView Windows Authentication SWIFT

Tags: ios, windows, swift, uiwebview, windows-authentication

I have a problem with the UIWebView. I cant open a Website with Windows Authentication... In the Safari Browser a pop-up appears, therefor in the WebView Control happened nothing.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Here my code:

```
    let url = NSURL (string: "http://inside.domain.com");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    browser.loadRequest(requestObj);
```

I also set the Info.plist.....

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your username is myUserName and password is myPassword

Now modifying your piece of code

```
    let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: "http://inside.domain.com");

    urlComponents.user = "myUserName";
    urlComponents.password = "myPassword";

    let url = urlComponents.URL;

    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    browser.loadRequest(requestObj);
```